# Clojure swap atom with map values

Tags: clojure, atomic

I want to `assoc`iate values of a map into an `atom`.
I could do it like :

```
  (defonce config (atom {}))
  (swap! config assoc :a "Aaa")
  (swap! config assoc :b "Bbb")
```

But it is repetitive, and makes several calls to `swap!`.
I would like to do something like that :

```
(swap! config assoc  {:a "Aaa"
                      :b "Bbb"})
;; this doesn't work :
;; Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: core$assoc
```

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the documentation for `assoc`:

```
=> (doc assoc)
-------------------------
clojure.core/assoc
([map key val] [map key val & kvs])
  assoc[iate]. When applied to a map, returns a new map of the
    same (hashed/sorted) type, that contains the mapping of key(s) to
    val(s). When applied to a vector, returns a new vector that
    contains val at index. Note - index must be <= (count vector).
nil
```

`assoc` doesn't take a map. It takes pairs of keys and vals:

```
user=> (assoc {} :a 1 :b 2)
{:a 1, :b 2}
user=> (let [x (atom {})]
                    #_=> (swap! x assoc :a 1 :b 2)
                    #_=> x)
#object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x227513c5 {:status :ready, :val {:a 1, :b 2}}]
```

By the way, you should always isolate your updates to an atom to a single `swap!`. By doing two swaps as above, you're allowing other threads to potentially clobber the referenced data. A single `swap!` keeps everything atomic.

---

**N.B.** `merge` behaves as you were imagining:

```
user=> (merge {} {:a 1 :b 1})
{:a 1, :b 1}
user=> (let [x (atom {})]
                    #_=> (swap! x merge {:a 1 :b 2})
                    #_=> x)
#object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x1be09e1b {:status :ready, :val {:a 1, :b 2}}]
```